# if statment not working with python widget

Tags: python, if-statement, widget, ipywidgets

I am working on a `Jupyter Notebook` in which I am creating a `tab widget` in python using the following code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

tab_contents = ['P0', 'P1']
children = [widgets.Text(description=name) for name in tab_contents]
tab = widgets.Tab()
tab.children = children
for i in range(len(children)):
    tab.set_title(i, str(i))

if tab.selected_index ==0:
    vartest = 0
else:
    vartest = 1

display(tab)
```

In a different cell, I check the value of vartest by calling it

```
vartest
```

The problem is that independently of the tab I have selected, vartest is always 0. What I want is that when I am in tab `P0` (`tab.selected_index ==0`), vartest should be 0, when I am in `P1` (`tab.selected_index ==1`) vartest should be 1.

What am I missing?

-- EDIT --

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set an `observe` to change the value of the variable dynamically:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

tab_contents = ['P0', 'P1']
children = [widgets.Text(description=name) for name in tab_contents]
tab = widgets.Tab()
tab.children = children
for i in range(len(children)):
    tab.set_title(i, str(i))

def tab_toggle_var(*args):
    global vartest
    if tab.selected_index ==0:
        vartest = 0
    else:
        vartest = 1
tab.observe(tab_toggle_var)
tab_toggle_var()
display(tab)
```

Comment: When running your code in a jupyter cell and then calling `vartest` in another cell I get `NameError: vartest is not defined`. Did you have a different behaviour?. I have added a screenshot to demostrate the behaviour

Comment: Oh true! on this case you actually need to define `vartest` as global. I had forgotten about it. Correcting now

Comment: This almost works. When running for the first time the code (in a new kernel), the first run of `vartest` in the second cell gives `NameError`. Then, I select the other tab and when running again the second cell calling `vartest` it works! It seems the very first time it is run `vartest` is not recognised. Any idea of why? Hope it is clear

Comment: Yeap, I do: since `observe` doesn't run until there is some change in the widget `tab`, the first time you run it there is no `vartest`. Solved by running `tab_toggle_var()` once before display.

Comment: very nice trick thansk a lot for the help!! I will now adapt it to my script :)

Answer (score 0):

You set the values for `vartest` within the if statements, without having `vartest` declared "globally" (i.e. before the if statements)
Hence, the `vartest` variables only live within the if block and are not available after that.

When you call it, it is zero, because that is the default value, assigned by python.
Fix: declare `vartest` before the if statement

Comment: Even if you declare it inside the `if` statement, `vartest` is a global variable because it is outside of the scope of any function/class/package. Declaring `vartest` before won't change the result.

Comment: The problem is that the `if` statement is executed only once, when the cell is run. This single execution enters in the `if` statement and assigns `vartest` to 0 because by default `tab.selected_index` is 0.